# SQL statement same value could be in many fields, same table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table called `people`" in that table I have a value of `James` but the value could be in many different columns such as:

```
Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, and Name5
```

How can I write a SQL statement that will return all rows with the value of `James` regardless of what column it is in?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where 'James' in (name1,name2,name3,name4,name5)
```